# How do I get my iPhone app to perform functions depending on the time?

Tags: iphone, xcode, time

I want to learn how, for example, I could program a picture in Interface Builder to change between 3 pictures according to the time of day.

Or how I could program a certain UIButton to appear and disappear depending on the time of day—or even more specifically, the month of the year.

Where can i go to learn about this? And what is the formal name for this? Using time signatures? Or time stamp?

Comment: Do you want to change what appears in Xcode itself or do you want to change what appears in the app that Xcode builds from your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/) class allows you to inspect the current time (also see [Date and Time Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i), and the [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) class allows you to schedule tasks.